# How to omit .module in a React project (w/ Vite) when importing stylesheets

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, vite

I have just created a new React project w/ SASS and I wanted to use Vite instead of Webpack.
The project I used to previously work on would allow me to have named imports and omit .module from the imports like

```
import style from './styles/MyComponent.scss';

// applying a style in the jsx file
    <p className={style.myParagraph>
```

However vite returns this error and the styles won't be applied
`Default and named imports from CSS files are deprecated. Use the ?inline query instead. For example: import style from "./styles/MyComponent.scss?inline"`

Here's my vite.config.js and what I tried so far

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    modules: {
      include: /\.scss$/,
      scopeBehaviour: 'local',
      localsConvention: 'camelCase'
    },
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        include: /\.scss$/,
        localsConvention: 'camelCase'
      }
    },
  },
  build: {
    cssCodeSplit: false,
    minify: true,
  },
})
```

Comment: The solution is literally in the error, have you even tried it?

Comment: @Arkellys I did try it before posting and all that happened was just reseting the styles, I have posted picture in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing matches [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules).

Vite is only going to support CSS modules that respect the `.module` suffix. You can read more in [this closed issue on Vite's Github](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2981).

A solution I attempted on a previous Vite migration was to glob all CSS files used as modules and add the `.module` suffix. I know it is not optimal but it's the best I've got.

Alternatively, you could use a less opinionated bundler like Webpack or [rspack](https://www.rspack.dev/).

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `Default and named imports from CSS files are deprecated. Use the ?inline query instead` because its deprecated in Vite 4.

> Importing a css like:
>
> `import thing from './global.css';`
>
> Will fundamentally cause a double loading of CSS, since vite will emit a .css file, but it's likely that the CSS will also be used by the application code, being most likely used by the framework runtime to inject the style.
>
> https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/10762#issue-1432916886

So to fix it, change you import from:

```
import style from './styles/MyComponent.scss';
```

to:

```
import style from './styles/MyComponent.scss?inline';
```

Answer (score 0):

I did try the solution I got in the error right away and I thought it didn't work because it kinda reset all the styles and elements went from

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIXGi.png

To

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJojQ.png

Also I read the docs https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#disabling-css-injection-into-the-page and thought `?inline` query would simply disable the style.

```
The automatic injection of CSS contents can be turned off via the ?inline query parameter. In this case, the processed CSS string is returned as the module's default export as usual, but the styles aren't injected to the page.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).